# Can linkshare.com be used to track free app conversions in the Apple app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I know many developers are using linkshare.com as an affiliate to track app conversions for paid apps. Does linkshare.com provide conversion data for free apps? All signs point to no but I thought I would ask.

We want to be able to track particular marketing campaigns with referrer codes and see how many downloads result from each campaign.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no. "Sales" of free apps are not returned in either LinkShare's or TradeDoubler's report.  You will, of course, see all of the other items the user bought during that 72 hour period that your affiliate cookie was active but those again will only be paid apps, music, movies, etc.

Even if you were using the Signature Tracking provided by LinkShare to track specific campaigns you are still going to have a hard time determining if the sale that is reported in your Signature Orders report was specifically your app or a competitors app at a similar price as the reporting is only at category level.

Good luck!